# Installing Certificate on Android TV Over Adb Command

Tags: android, certificate, adb, television

Is there a way to install Adguard Certificate (adguard.crt) on an Android TV? I installed Adguard on my TV and set up everything except for HTTPS Filtering. When I click on activate, the certificate install screen flashes but when I click on install it says not installed. On my TV there is no Settings -> Security -> Certificates option. So I can't handle it.

Up to now, I managed many customizations on my TV over ADB Shell. Is it possible to install adguard.crt over ADB Shell?

I read many things on different forums but there isn't any clear explanation for that.

Your help is appreciated. If you know please reply me.

My Android TV is Philips 49PUS7502/12 with Android 8.0 Oreo. It's not rooted and don't want to root before warranty expires. USB Debugging and Adb over wireless is active.

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible on Android TV without root. Sorry!